# Can I decipher compression and DPI settings of a TIFF image in Window XP?

Tags: compression, tiff, dpi

I have the following (weird) task: I have a set of black-and-white TIFF image files on a Windows XP system. I am not allowed to install any software on that system or access the internet from it. I need to determine two things for each TIFF:

1. Its DPI (resolution), if given
2. Its compression settings (including "no compression")

If I open a TIFF file in MS Paint, I can only see #1. What can I do to get both?

I tried hex-viewing a file in a text editor, but I don't know where the relevant info is stored and how (could not find enough info [**here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Compression))

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#TIFF_Compression_Tag (same article, just farther down the page).

Comment: Also, from the notes in the same article, http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf .

Comment: Thanks. Should have read wiki more carefully... :-)

Comment: I remember TIFF being quite complex to unpick, so if you can't put software *on* the system can you copy the TIFF files *off* it and inspect them off-line? And does MS Paint really show you resolution? I just see image size in pixels...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above: [section of Wikipedia TIFF page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#TIFF_Compression_Tag)